# PowerShell script that deleted quicklaunch entries

Tags: powershell, quick-launch

I'm running a PowerShell script that deletes about 10 entries per minute. Is there a way to do this more efficiently/quicker, i.e. directly from the database? How can this be achieved?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://site
$qlNave = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$i = 1
ForEach ($Node in $qlNave)
{
  if ($node.Title -eq "something")
  {
    $node.Delete()
  }
  $i++
}
$web.Dispose()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I did it with the following code,

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$FindString = “something”
Get-SPSite http:/sitecollectionurl/ | get-spweb -limit all | foreach-object{
    $web = $_
    $_.Navigation.QuickLaunch | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Children | ForEach-Object {
            if($_.title -eq $FindString){
                $node = $_
                $node.delete()
                Write-Host “Deleted node from ” $web “-” $web.url
                }
            }
       }
  }

Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

OR

try the below codes too

**To delete the link from the Quick Launch**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$webURL="http://serverName:1111/sites/SPSiteDataQuery/"
$web=Get-SPWeb $webURL
$navigationNodeColl=$web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$heading = $navigationNodeColl | where { $_.Title -eq "Libraries" }
$link = $heading.Children | where { $_.Title -eq "Shared Documents" }
$link.Delete()
Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

**To delete the heading from the Quick Launch**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$webURL="http://serverName:1111/sites/SPSiteDataQuery/"
$web=Get-SPWeb $webURL
$navigationNodeColl=$web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$heading = $navigationNodeColl | where { $_.Title -eq "Libraries" }
$heading.Delete()
Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

[Source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/quick-launch-navigation-in-sharepoint-2010-part2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$subsite= Get-SPWeb $subSiteUrl

$node = $subsite.Navigation.QuickLaunch | where { $_.TitleResource.Value -eq $titleToRemove}

if($node -ne $null)
{
   $node.Delete()
}
```