# How to hide Quick Launch in Sharepoint page without customizing code in AllItems.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

To hide the Quick Launch in Sharepoint2010 List i.e. `AllItems.aspx` page I use:

```
.ms-quicklaunch
{
display:none;
}
```

In my scenario I have more than 200+ Document Libraries and List, in which each and every time I need to customize the code. Is there any out of box features?

I have tried by going to `Site Setting`-->`Tree View`-->`Navigation` and uncheck the `Quick Launch` box but here still `All Site Contents` and `Recycle bin` is visible.

Comment: you can customize your masterpage

Comment: I would say you need to customize your masterpage.

Comment: You can use PowerShell with CSOM framework to implement the functionality. 1)   access the spsite 2) get-spweb 3) use foreach splist that has the type == DocumentLibrary then get the allitems.aspx file and apply the css.

Comment: Refer this link using SSOM : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83249/powershell-script-that-deleted-quicklaunch-entries,                                                  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://your-sharepoint-site-url"
#Process Quick launch
for ($i = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
{  $node = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch[$i];
    if($node.Title -eq "Recent") 
        {         $node.Delete();Write-host "Recent section removed from $($web.Title)"   } }

Comment: foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)  { if (!(list is SPDocumentLibrary))
                            {                                continue;                      }
               if (list.Fields.ContainsField(strFieldName))                            {
                                //TODO, modify set of items                            }                        }

Answer (score 0):

Please refer  [this](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/03/managing-quick-launch-navigation-in.html)  link  and  [this](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/hide-recent-from-sharepoint-2013-quick-launch.html) and modify above mentioned script, I have given and you will get your functionality. Below is a sample one :

```
  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction 
  SilentlyContinue
 $web = Get-SPWeb "http://your-sharepoint-site-url"
  #Process Quick launch
      for ($i = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Count-1; $i -ge 0; $i--)
        {
    $node = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch[$i];
        {
          $node.Delete();
         Write-host "quick launch removed from $($web.Title)"
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you already using custom style template for your site? This could and probably should be added using such and implement it to a masterpage as already suggested in the comments.

By using a style template the changes can be tracked better compared to changes done using PowerShell. Also you can switch back to use the Quick Launch menu on a smaller scope by using different style template. Also the styling is auto-applied assuming the same masterpage is inherited on new sub-sites, pages, etc.